# В чем проблема регистрации? на php

Tags: php

Нужно чтобы показывался текст что пользователь не ввел символы в строку. Написал, проверал, но почему-то ничего нету. Буду благодарен за помощь)

```
<?php
    require "db.php";

    $data = $_POST;
    if ( isset($data['do_signup']) ) {
        //проверка регистрации

        $errors = array();
        if (trim($data['naming']) == '') {
            $errors[] = 'Введите ваше имя!';
        }

        if (trim($data['login']) == '') {
            $errors[] = 'Введите логин!';
        }

        if ($data['psw'] == '') {
            $errors[] = 'Введите пароль!';
        }

        if ($data['psw_repeat'] != $data['psw']) {
            $errors[] = 'Повторите ещё раз пароль!';
        }

        if (trim($data['email']) == '') {
            $errors[] = 'Введите Email!';
        }

        if ( empty($errors) ) {
            // регистрация пройшла успешно
        }else{
            echo array_shift($errors);
        }   
    };
?>
```

Comment: А в HTML в теге input параметр required не пробовали?

Comment: Я хотел бы, чтобы, показывало сообщение что от пользователя нужно, я уже решил проблему :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ( empty($errors) ) {`

empty проверяет, считается ли переменная пустой. Переменная считается пустой, если она не существует или её значение равно false

Comment: empty([]) === true, https://3v4l.org/4ELH1

Comment: Вот именно, что `empty` проверяет только на эти два условия, но не проверяет на `is_null` и `!== ""` так что Ваше решение не совсем верное

Comment: спасибо. Вроде как помогло

Answer (score 0):

Позволю себе немного упростить Ваш код, исправить в нем ошибки и дать некоторые советы по мере написания

```php
    require "db.php";

    $data = $_POST;
    if ( isset($data['do_signup']) ) {
        $errors = [];
        //Типовая проверка всех полей - кстати я бы поле с паролем на пустоту предварительно `trim`-нув его не проверял т.к пользователь вполне может использовтаь пробел вначале или конце пароля
        foreach(['naming' => 'Введите ваше имя!', 'login' => 'Введите логин!', 'psw' => 'Введите логин!', 
                 'psw_repeat' => 'Подтвердите пароль!', 'email' => 'Введите Email!'] as $fieldName => $errorMessage ) {
            if ( !isset( $data[ $fieldName ] ) || is_null( $data[ $fieldName ] ) && trim( $data[ $fieldName ] ) == '' ) {
                $errors[] = $errorMessage;
            }
        }
        //Отдельно проверяем что пароль и его подтверждение совпадают, Но только в том случае если они введены
        if ( isset( $data[ 'psw' ] ) && isset( $data[ 'psw_repeat' ] ) && $data[ 'psw' ] != $data[ 'psw_repeat' ] ) {
            $errors[] = 'Пароль и его подтверждение не совпадают!';
        }
        //Проверяем что ошибок валидации формы авторизации не было
        if ( count( $errors ) > 0 ) {
            //Есть ошибки
        } else {
           //Нет ошибок
           //В случае ошибки я бы еще выводил сообщение об ошибке ПОД самим полем и ставил в него фокус
        }
    }
```